# elasticsearch не доступен вне сервера

Tags: elasticsearch

Проблема такая. У меня сайт на yii работает с elasticsearch и при его вызове http://localhost:9200/nysite/activity/_search выдаёт Client error response
[status code] 400
При этом, если я перейду по этой ссылке через curl в консоли - всё ок.

Куда копать?

Запустил мэппинг. Ошибка. 
В логах:

```
[2018-10-15 08:50:11,046][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [Mastermind of the UK] [florida] failed to create
MapperParsingException[Failed to parse mapping [cities]: Mapper for [name] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
[mapper [name] has different [index] values, mapper [name] has different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [name] has different [analyzer], mapper [name] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [omit_norms] across all types., mapper [name] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [name] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Mapper for [name] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
[mapper [name] has different [index] values, mapper [name] has different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [name] has different [analyzer], mapper [name] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [omit_norms] across all types., mapper [name] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [name] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]];
```

Comment: В сторону логов эластика, там должно быть написано, что именно не понравилось ему в запросе.

Comment: Дополнил, ошибка и при запуске мэппинга